# running code on BeagleBone using Cloud9 IDE

Tags: beagleboard, cloud9-ide

I am very new to BeagleBone. I have been using Arduino upto now.

I plug my BeagleBone into my Linux laptop, and connect BeagleBone to my router.

I can open Cloud9 off the board by browsing to 192...:3000. I want to load and run this code:
https://github.com/jadonk/bonescript

described here: http://www.gigamegablog.com/2012/01/05/beaglebone-coding-101-blinking-an-led/

On the File menu I can not find any option to create a new project. How am I suppose to load code into Cloud9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new project--you can simply create a new source file that is executable.  There is a small down-arrow to the right of the "Run" button.  There, you can select to add a new run configuration to execute your new file.

By-the-way, thanks to mDNS/Bonjour, you can likely discover Cloud9 on your network using http://beaglebone.local:3000/

Comment: thx, also I am very interested in mDNS/Bonjour that you mentioned.

Comment: What file path do you have there?

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble getting the Cloud9 "Run" button to work on a BeagleBone. I posted a question here if you have any tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501758/unable-to-run-files-in-cloud9-on-beaglebone