# Unable to run bonescript files in Cloud9 on BeagleBone

Tags: node.js, beagleboard, cloud9-ide

I am having trouble using the Cloud9 IDE to run files which use bonescript on a BeagleBone with the pre-installed version of Angstrom Linux. I am using Cloud9 at http://beaglebone.local:3000 in Chrome 18 on OSX 10.7.

When I run the [Bonescript](https://github.com/jadonk/bonescript) blinkled.js sample code Cloud9 outputs this error:

```
Output
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
       ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/cloud9'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:326:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:271:25)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:430:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

If I try adding a file path in the run configuration as suggested [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050478/running-code-on-beaglebone-using-cloud9-ide) I get this error in the Console (in bright red mind you):

```
[C9 Server Exception 2] undefined
```

At this point Cloud9 also stops responding and I have to reload the page to attempt to use it further.

If I add "blinkled.js" as the file path I get this error:

```
'inotify' not loaded
If desired, try installing it with:
  curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | bash
  npm install inotify
'fibers' not loaded
If desired, try installing it with:
  curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | bash
  npm install fibers
Delay operations loops will consume CPU cycles
Invoke using 'node-fibers' if node version < 0.5.2
```

No idea what I should put in there.

I've been Googling these various errors for about 24 hours now.

This seems like a great tool, if I can only get it to work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

After realizing the opkg had failed to load the required inotify and fibers packages I installed them manually and tried again. Now I get this error on the command line:

```
# node blinkled.js 
gpio: 38 already exported.
{ [Error: EBUSY, resource busy or locked] errno: 10, code: 'EBUSY', syscall: 'write' }
Unable to export gpio: 56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I realize there were multiple problems:

**First,** I should have checked the documentation to get node.js to work. I just assumed alert() was a function when I should have been using console.log(). So once I realized this I was able to run this file in Cloud9:

```
var hello = "hello world"
console.log(hello);
```

**Second,** When I tried to install the libraries (inotify and fibers) using the npm package manager it placed them in the node_modules directory in my working directory:

```
/home/root/
```

... not the default Cloud9 root directory as I assumed it would:

```
/var/lib/cloud9
```

**Third,** my pins were already exported, which was fixed by simply restarting the BeagleBone.

**Finally,** I found that creating a new instance in my home directory with the latest version of [bonescript](https://github.com/jadonk/bonescript) allowed me to run the [blinkled.js](https://github.com/jadonk/bonescript/blob/master/blinkled.js) sample file, as well as [this file which tests all analog pins on the BeagleBone](https://gist.github.com/2794039) from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You might do a 'git pull' in /var/lib/cloud9 to get an update.  One thing I've added is an 'analogRead' function.

Answer (score 0):

i bough beagle bone rev. A4. this kind of error is comming on that also.
i have just make new SD card with latest angstrom image, and then after blinky is working properly.